# std::find how does it work? operator==

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a class

```
class Point
{
public:
  Point() {}
  Point(int _col, int _row) : row(_row), col(_col) {}
  int row, col;
};
```

how can I use std::find() to check whether the point is already in vector? DO I have to overload operator== ?

I am trying to do this

```
#include <algorithm>

if(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), x) != v.end()) {
    /* v contains x */
} else {
    /* v does not contain x */
}
```

Almost every answer I find on Stack Overflow suggest using find to check whether the object is in `std::vector` but none of them explains whether it compares the pointer of objects or the actual values of the object.

Comment: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is usually a great place to look up how functions/classes from the standard library work. If you haven't yet, I suggest reading that page (and generally getting into the habit of checking it if you have a question of how something works).

Comment: @Cornstalks: I did it says it uses operator== for comparisons but the example below uses primitive int in an array. I did not find any example for an object. FYI coming from Java background. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: That's a terribly dangerous default constructor!

Comment: The mechanics/code is the same for `int` and for other types, like `Point`. It will still use `operator==`. If your class does not have an `operator==`, you will get a compilation error (or you should use the version of `std::find` that lets you pass in your own predicate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard (draft N3242) says (in section 25.2.5 [alg.find]) that `std::find`:

> *Returns*: The first iterator `i` in the range `[first,last)` for which the following corresponding conditions hold: `*i == value`[...]. Returns `last` if no such iterator is found.

Your question of whether it will search based on the value or the address of the object depends on how `operator==` is implemented. The simple answer is: `std::find` will return an iterator to the object for which `operator==` returned true.

Usually, this will just be a value-based comparison (because `operator==` is usually implemented to compare the values of two objects), and so you should generally expect `std::find` to search the range for the value you've provided (not the address of the object you provided).

It's possible for `operator==` to be implemented such that it [compares based on address](http://ideone.com/sAUWmr), like so:

```
bool operator==(const Point& left, const Point& right) {
    return &left == &right;
}
```

Using this `operator==` will compare addresses, and so `std::find` will search for an object that has the same address as the one you've provided. It's generally a bad idea to implement `operator==` like this, though. Most people would implement `operator==` like so:

```
bool operator==(const Point& left, const Point& right) {
    return left.row == right.row && left.col == right.col;
}
```

which, when used with `std::find`, will [compare `Point`s based on their values](http://ideone.com/Mt3rOO).

Comment: the last code snippet is what I was looking for. Thanks1

Answer (score 0):

Unless your types are <s>PODs</s> fundamental types, you will need to provide an equality function, member or not.

There are two fundamental versions of `std::find`, one that assumes an equality operator and the other uses an equality function you supply.

I recommend that you add `operator==` and `operator<` to any class that will be compared for equality or ordered.

Here's an updated version of your class:

```
class Point
{
  int x;  // These are private by default.
  int y; 
  public:  
    Point(int new_x, int new_y) : x(new_x), y(new_y)
    { ; }
    bool operator==(const Point& p) const
    {
      return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
    }
};
```

The member method `operator==` allows comparison without exposing the values to friends or the public.

If you want to use a free standing comparison function, you will need to either make the values public or make the function a friend:

```
class Point
{
  int x;  // These are private by default.
  int y; 
  public:  
    Point(int new_x, int new_y) : x(new_x), y(new_y)
    { ; }
    friend bool operator==(const Point& a, const Point& b);
};

bool operator==(const Point& a, const Point& b)
{
    return (a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y);
}
```

If you want to use the free standing function with `std::find`, the example would be:

```
std::vector<Point> point_container;
//...
Point p;
std::vector<Point>::const_iterator iter;
iter = std::find(point_container.begin(), point_container.end(),
                 p,
                 Equal_Points);
```

Where `Equal_Points` is a free standing function that can compare the members of two Points.

Comment: *"Unless your types are PODs"* -- or *if* your types are PODs. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you. Why does PODness matter?

Comment: The compiler emits comparison functions for POD types such as `int, float,` and `char`.  Anything more complex requires a comparison operator because the definition of "equal" depends on class or structure. For example, a class may have 5 members but only 2 are used for determining equality.

Comment: For fundamental types, sure. But not for POD types in general.

Comment: I think you're conflating POD with [fundamental type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). [A default `operator==` is not provided for PODs](http://ideone.com/BKxFTJ).