# C++ Vector of Object searching for which object contains a specific last name error C2678 binary '==': no operator found

Tags: c++, vector, find

C++ is not really in my skills, so I have vector of objects which is obviously several copies of a class.

My class is named "Contact", and my function I am property passing in my vector objects as reference.

As soon as I try to add in this `find`, I guess an error

```
void Contact::searchContactByLastName(string name, vector<Contact>& allContacts) {

    cout << "In SearchContactByLastName \n";  // 

    unsigned int count = allContacts.size();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        
        //this works 
        cout << " Last Name " << i << " = " << allContacts[i].getLastName() << endl;
        // THIS IS WHAT DOES NOT WORK, even outside the for loop ....
        if (std::find(allContacts.begin(), allContacts.end(), name) != allContacts.end()) {
            // Found the item
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you defined an `operator==()` for your `Contact` class? Without that, how can `find` look for a match?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::find how does it work? operator==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816245/stdfind-how-does-it-work-operator)

Comment: You could check in the loop with something like `if (allContacts[i].getLastName() == name) { ... }` I'm assuming that `getLastName()` returns a `std::string`.

Comment: hi,  @AdrianMole   I am not familiar with operator==()    yikes

Comment: The suggested duplicate has answers that provide outlines of how to define such an operator.

Comment: Use `std::find_if`; `std::find` tries to match the elements using `==`...

Comment: Thx everyone.   I certainly need to spent more time with C++,   for now the   if statement by Retired Ninja is a simple solution that works for what I'm doing.   I do want to learn about the operator and find etc..  but in a time crunch.   thx

Comment: @TomStickel -- *but in a time crunch* -- You should have chose `std::find_if`.  Then you don't need `operator==`, and only a minor adjustment to the code you have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you probably don't want to implement the `==` operator to match `Contract` and `std::string`, it's a good idea to `std::find_if` allowing you to pass the matching functionality as parameter.

```
if (std::find_if(allContacts.begin(), allContacts.end(), [&name](Contract const& contract) {return name == contract.getLastName();}) != allContacts.end()) {
    // Found the item
}
```